# Scala vs Groovy vs Java for testing

Tags: java, scala, testing, groovy, integration-testing

If you need to choose the language to write your integration tests, what language would you pick? (from the above, or maybe another language).

The requirements that I think the language should meet are at least the following: fast, reasonable IDE, easy to learn.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, apparently there is no place for [that](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143579/scala-vs-groovy-vs-java-for-testing) kind of questions all over stackexchange. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/) then? I'm not a user, but it seems to me they are receptive of broad, open-ended questions.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: Please don't suggest users crosspost.  I'd rather you flag for mod attention and suggest we migrate it.  Saves StackExchange-wide aggravation.  Getting a question like this acceptable is *very hard* due to its subjective nature.  Since you already have an accepted answer, editing to make it "good subjective" is kind of pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say Groovy is probably the best choice.

- It offers significant advantages over Java (closures, list/map literals, very compact implementation of mocks)
- It's very easy to learn incrementally for anyone familiar with Java (Scala is much more different, and many also consider the language inherently more difficult)
- Groovy is pretty well supported by IDE plugins by now
- The speed of the language is almost certainly not going to matter for integration tests, as the system being tested will probably contain much larger overheads (especially if a database is involved)

However, if you're already using Scala elsewhere (especially in the system under test) and can assume youre developers to be familiar with it, Scala may be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks. Though Groovy eclipse plugin makes some troubles for me.

Comment: @Noam: It used to be a lot worse. And that should be a perfectly on-topic question :)

Comment: Test code should be refactored to patterns too. Just because of that, scala is a better option. Unit Test in scala are faster (one to two orders of magnitude), and that is the kind of unit test we all like.

Comment: @Chechus: the question is not about unit tests, though.